# Migrating from Flex 3.2 to 4.0

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, air, flex4

I have an app built in flex 3.2, and would like to start using some spark components within that same app. Are there any pitfalls to look out for.
Is it possible to use the old 3.2 components in the same app or Will I have to rebuild them. 
Would like to get the heads up from anyone that has done the same, before I make the plunge.

Thanks

Comment: Near-duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563482/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post has some pretty good info - [Migrating to Flex 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650347/migrating-to-flex-4)

You may run into some small issues with mixing and matching Halo/Spark components when it comes to some of the layouts, but in general they work pretty well together side by side.

The major issue is CSS because the Spark components are less CSS-friendly than Halo.

=Ryan

Comment: The Ryan Stewart? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, custom components extending / based on Halo components of Flex 3.2 will continue to work as will the default Halo components.